# What is the difference between "Multiple" and "Single" for View Controller Presentation?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I've been working on an OS X app in Xcode. An option that completely perplexes me is "Presentation", with the two options "Single" and "Multiple" what does this attribute do?

[image]

Comment: Running Xcode 7.1.1 and do not see this option.

Comment: @rocky select the "controller" object on a scene in a Storyboard. This option is still present as of XCode 7.2.1 - It should also be available on .xibs.

Comment: this is all I see: http://imgur.com/U1oFL5v

Comment: @rocky Are you seeing this in an .xib or .nib file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this was actually "obvious" once I used it.

Basically, this feature causes a window to be displayed once, or multiple times if the corresponding segue in a storyboard has been triggered multiple times.

To see this in action, add a create a storyboard with a view controller in it. The place a button on the view, and an additional window controller. Create a segue between the button and the window controller to "show" the window controller.

Click on the window controller and toggle between the two *Presentation* options. When you run it, you will find that one case will create multiple instances of the window, while the other will create a single instance of the window.

Like I said, obvious, but had to actually use it to figure it out.

Comment: ~I have changed it to `single` but seems nothing changed, still be able to open multiple windows when I keep clicking the button;~ Found the issue, the sege was pointing to the `Window` instead of the `Controller`.