# How to prevent multiple instances of the same window of a Menu Bar App from opening in macOS in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard, nswindowcontroller

I am making a MacOS Menu Bar app (Xcode 11.3.1, Swift 5.1.3) and in its popup window (that pops up when clicking on the icon in the menu bar - this is my Main.storyboard) it has a button to open the Preferences window.

So I actually need to show the Preferences window from the Main.storyboard that is on another storyboard called Preferences.storyboard.

Problem is that as many times I click the button on the Main storyboard a new Preferences window comes up on screen.

My initial code in the ViewController.swift of my Main.storyboard was:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    private var preferencesWindowController: NSWindowController?

    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Shows the Preferences window on button click in popup bubble
    @IBAction func showPreferences(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if preferencesController == nil {
            let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: nil)
            preferencesController = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as? NSWindowController
        }
        
        if (preferencesController != nil) {
            preferencesController?.showWindow(sender)
        }
        
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }

}
```

This did not prevented showing new instances of the Preferences window upon clicking the button.

So I made the trick with the "lazy" var putting this code in the ViewController.swift of my Main.storyboard:

(as suggested at [How to prevent multiple instances of the same window from opening in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60835055/12969395) - note: there the example shows clicking a standard menu item, not a button in a menu bar popup window that seemed to fire an @IBAction code in my AppDelegate.swift, but for my menu bar app I do not have a menu to show at all, rather I would do all actions from the popup window of the menu bar icon)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    private lazy var preferencesWindowController: NSWindowController? = {
        let storyboard: NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as? NSWindowController
    }()

    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Shows the Preferences window on button click in popup bubble
    @IBAction func showPreferences(_ sender: Any) {
        preferencesWindowController?.showWindow(self)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }

}
```

On the Preferences.storyboard my `Storyboard Entry Point` and `Initial Controller` for the Preferences window is its `Window Controller` (in its `Window Controller Scene`) that contains a `Tab View Controller` (in its `Tab View Controller Scene`) with the settings.

I also did set the `Presentation` attribute of the `Window Controller` of the Preferences window to "Single" (as suggested at [What is the difference between "Multiple" and "Single" for View Controller Presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30563367/12969395)).

I also tried using IB only: no IBAction coded, just connected the button to the built-in `ViewController showPreferences:`

All the same result: I can open a new Preferences window with a new click on the button as may times as I click.

What do I miss?

Comment: Use a window controller instance in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: I had the same code in AppDelegate but I noticed that it was connected to the Preferences menu item (again that is not shown) of  Main.storyboard. I removed that connection but just cannot connect the IBAction code to the button of Main.storyboard. Is that what you mean? If so, why cannot I connect the button to the IBAction code in AppDelegate?

Otherwise, could you show me the code you mean, please?

Comment: Good! I got it! The problem was that in IB I connected the button's `Sent actions/action` to an `@IBAction` in ViewController.swift, but it needed to be connected to `First responder`'s  showPreferencesWindow function in AppDelegate.swift